# How to define inner class constructor when using class template in the outer class?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

How can I define a nested class constructor, when the outer class is a template?

I tried removing the template parameter and it works. But I need that value for something I am doing.
I tried with g++ with and without `-std=c++11` (no difference). 
I do not want to put my code in the header file, so I didn't try it that way

```
#include <cstddef>

template <size_t M_SIZE=20>
class Outer{
    class Inner{
        Inner();
    };
};
//Outer::Inner::Inner() {}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

It happens when you uncomment that line

> ```
> cl.cpp:9:1: error: 'Outer' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
> Outer::Inner::Inner() {}
> ^
> cl.cpp:4:7: note: 'Outer' declared here
> class Outer{
>       ^
> 1 error generated.
> ```

shell returned 1

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
template<size_t mSize> Outer<mSize>::Inner::Inner() {}
```

But as usual, if you're planning to define your templated entities in a separate file, you'll have to explicitly instantiate them in your header:

```cpp
template class Outer<42>;
```